# I am using pyautogui to detect the mouse position. I have a tkinter window, but the pyautogui only works when i close the tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui

I am creating a chinese Checkers Ai. I am trying to detect the mouse. I used pyautogui.

```
from pyautogui import *
while True:
    if position()[0] < 445 & position()[0] > 405:
        print("Mouse detected.")
```

I also have a tkinter window, but lets just say this is my tkinter code.:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
..................
root.mainloop()
```

So the entire code would be:

```
from pyautogui import *
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
..................
root.mainloop()
while True:
    if position()[0] < 445 & position()[0] > 405:
        print("Mouse detected.")
```

But when i ran it, it would only detect if i closed the tkinter window.

What happened??

Comment: By any chance were you on windows with the tkinter window running as admin?

Comment: I use a macbook.

Comment: Just making sure. In that case it is likely that you need to run this as two separate python programs, or use multi threading or multiprocessing. The mainloop() function isn’t exiting until you close the tkinter window.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh........................................................... so i might need to put the loop before the mainloop() function?

Comment: But when i try that, the tkinter imagery doesn't show up.

Comment: do you understand what @soundstripe said ? Are you familiar with programming (loops, threads) ? "The mainloop() function isn’t exiting until you close the tkinter window." Same applies to your while loop.

Comment: I know what he said. I decided to use multi threads, but i have some problems with it. You can look at my other question on multithreading!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multi threading or create two different files with your functions and then run them.

Comment: I am beginning at python, and i don't know how to link different files in python. I self teach myself via the internet.

Comment: Ok, now i have another problem. I tried multithreading, but the terminal returned: '2018-11-11 16:16:46.650 python[22868:7948287] WARNING: NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future.' followed by a bunch of data of where it called from. What do i do?